# Debugging a c function in a R package

Tags: c, r

I want to debug the c function of an R package using `R -d gdb`, but I get the following after setting breakpoint at c function `C_MIM()`, I got the following information and also "cannot find bound of the current function" so I could not print out any variable value in this case. Is there something I am doing wrong? Or for some R package, it is not possible to debug?

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x00007fffdee0035f in C_MIM ()
   from /home/sunxd/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/praznik/libs/praznik.so
(gdb) list
76      in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function C_MIM,
which has no line number information.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffdddfa700 (LWP 21179)]
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
0x00007ffff45c707e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
```

Answer (score 0):

it turns out one must have the source code and compile the R package using specific gcc/cc options.